# Selection area with click and drag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

Could someone explain me how to make a click and drag feature with jquery/javascript/css/html? It should work just like the desktop does when you click and drag, forming that "rectangle" area. Any idea on how should I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1039986/how-to-implement-a-drag-and-drop-div-from-scratch and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7278409/html5-drag-and-drop-to-move-a-div-anywhere-on-the-screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a fairly easy feature to implement using [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/). They have a [sortable](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/), [draggable](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/) and [droppable](http://jqueryui.com/droppable/) feature already built. You simply include jQuery and jQueryUI and then instantiate the feature using selector targeting. jQueryUI also has pretty decent documentation and good examples on each feature. Hope this helps!

Comment: I was just about to recommend Draggable from the jQuery UI!

Comment: Yeah, JUI is awesome! And with the touch features for mobile, its like having a native app!

Comment: Thanks very much to you both for the fast responses!